# Is it possible to extract value of a parameter in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was trying to generalize a module that had the parameter "int max=15". Is there some way to set an output of the module to the value of the parameter. For example, if the parameter max was set to the value 8, zout would be set to the value of 4'b1000.

```
    module example
    #(parameter int max=15,
    parameter int bw=$clog2(m))
    (input logic ............,
    .........................,
    output logic [b-1:0] zout);
    assign zout = [value of max];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign it:

```
module example #(
    parameter int max=15,
    parameter int b=$clog2(max+1)
) (
    output logic [b-1:0] zout
);

    assign zout = max[b-1:0];

endmodule
```

Comment: My log keeps saying "continuous assignment width mismatch, 4 bits (lhs) versus 32 bits (rhs), source info: assign max=m"

Comment: That's because int is 32 bits, but it should still work that way. I updated the answer to match it up, try that.

Comment: You are an absolute beaut Justin :)